# Email is not Delivering using Sendgrid SMTP

Tags: email, smtp, codeigniter-3, sendgrid

I am using CI library to send an email using Sendgrid smtp.

but it is not giving any response, neither email is sending.

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol']  = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'api key name';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'api key';
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
$config['smtp_keepalive'] = 'TRUE';

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('test@test.com', FROM_NAME);

$this->email->to($email);
extract($arr_var);
$sub=addslashes($row['subject']);
eval("\$subject= \"$sub\";");
$body=addslashes($row['message']);
eval("\$message= \"$body\";");
if ($subject!='') {
    $this->email->subject(stripslashes($subject));
} else {
    $this->email->subject($row['subject'].' - '.$this->config->item('app_title'));
}
    $this->email->message($message);
    $bool=$this->email->send();
```

Using above code i am sending en email CI v3 but it I am not receiving any email?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

Two things stand out to me here.

First, where you set the smtp username, it should be the string `"apikey"` (see [the instructions for sending with SMTP here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-smtp#send-an-smtp-email-using-telnet)).

Second, the from address you are sending from is "test@test.com". SendGrid requires you to [verify the identity you send from](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity). You either need go through [Single Sender Verification](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) or [Domain Authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) and then use an email address that you have verified to send the emails from.

Once you have sorted those two bits out, your emails should send successfully.

Comment: `apikey` i am using as username ...and I also verify the sender verification... but still i am having issue, but when i use any other email service that email is going correctly but when i use sendgrid setting i am not receiving email.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Or more importantly, does `$this->email->send()` return `true`? Are you able to use [`print_debugger`](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::print_debugger) to see what is going on?

Comment: i have tried `echo $this->email->print_debugger(); die(); ` it says  **Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.**  Why this error is coming..as i am using apikey as string which i created as `username` and password which is auto generated by sengrid..but still it says it is bad username and password ?

Comment: So, there is something wrong with your credentials. The password should be a [API key that you generated here in your dashboard](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys) and you should ensure that it has permission to send email.

Comment: Is  `Single Sender Verification` or `Domain Authentication` both step required as i just do  Single Sender Verification?

Comment: I also copy the password from where i create apikey..which is by default started with `SG`

Comment: You only need to have completed Single Sender Verification or Domain Authentication in order to send an email. If you have done Single Sender Verification then you can use the email that you verified in that process. If you have completed Domain Authentication then you can use any email address on the domain you have authenticated.

Comment: When you created the API Key, what permissions did you give it?

Comment: I provide full access to an API

Comment: I'm stumped on why you can't send through SMTP if the credentials are all correct. As an alternative, could you try sending email with the REST API, using the [SendGrid PHP library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php)?

Comment: I try this lib, when it runs it says `Class 'SendGrid\Mail\Mail' not found`

Comment: Sounds like you’re not including the library correctly. Might be worth asking a new question and sharing how you have this set up.

Comment: I iclude this lib in this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542971/how-to-use-sendgrid-api-library-in-codeigniter-as-thirdparty-library

Comment: Like I said, it’s best to ask a new question. It’s probably too much to fit in comments like this.